# How to link or connect two XML files used in Odoo

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-8

Currently, I am working on ODOO. During my project, I have to use various XML files. I tried to link two XML files using id's but it showed External id not found. So how can I access the fields of one XML file in another XML file or how can I connect these two XML files.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you forgot to use `module name`:

```
<field name="inherit_id" ref="module_name.xml_id"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the module name

module='example'
File1.xml

```
...
<record id="record_id_1">
    ... 
</record>
```

File 2.xml

```
...
<record id="record_id_2">
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="example.record_id_1"/>
    ... 
</record>
```

if you already did it but it doesn't work, post your code.

Comment: Can you help me, how to specify module name?

Comment: as i wrote above and also @zetys did below, if module name is "module" and your id is "record_id" you write "module.record_id" PS the module name is the name of the python package!

Comment: Thank you for your reply